# Testing for statistically significant difference between response categories from two merged samples

Tags: r, purrr, t-test

I have been asked to check if the differences for responses between year 1 and year 2 are statistically different. I made this table calculating the percent for each response category (0 to 10 and NA) for each year and then and calculated the difference in percentages. Is there a tidy map function where I can automatically filter every DV category  and then run a `t.test`? Can I append the result (`mutate%>%case_when`?) or do I have to write it out too?

```
dist3<- tibble::tribble(
            ~`DV`,~`Y1`, ~`Y2`, ~ `Difference`,
            "0", 8.21, 11.34, 8.21 - 11.34,
            "1",   3.05, 4.46,3.05 - 4.46,
            "2",   5.82, 7.41, 5.82 - 7.41,
            "3",  7.64,8.91, 7.64-8.91,
            "4",   6.60, 7.28, 6.60-7.28,
            "5",  20.89, 18.30, 20.89-18.30,
            "6",   7.56, 7.66, 7.56-7.66,
            "7",   9.34, 8.58, 9.34-8.58,
            "8",   7.86,6.69, 7.86-6.69,
            "9",   3.17, 3.16, 3.17-3.16,
            "10",  13.40, 11.18, 13.40-11.18,
            "NA",   6.46, 5.03, 6.46-5.03,
            "Total", 100, 100, 100.00-100.00)
```

Comment: Just to clarify, the ask is to check if the rate for each response category (number of people who picked 0 Y1 vs number of people who picked 0 Y2) is different. I'm using percentages because it doesn't make sense to compare # of people directly when the sample size varies. It is not a test of whether there is a statistical difference between response options (0 vs 1 etc) in Y1 and in Y2.

Answer (score 0):

I may have misunderstood, but I don't know if your question 'makes sense'; you can't perform a t-test on 'single observations' (i.e. the Y1/Y2 percentages for each DV), e.g.

```r
library(tidyverse)

dist3<- tibble::tribble(
  ~`DV`,~`Y1`, ~`Y2`, ~ `Difference`,
  "0", 8.21, 11.34, 8.21 - 11.34,
  "1",   3.05, 4.46,3.05 - 4.46,
  "2",   5.82, 7.41, 5.82 - 7.41,
  "3",  7.64,8.91, 7.64-8.91,
  "4",   6.60, 7.28, 6.60-7.28,
  "5",  20.89, 18.30, 20.89-18.30,
  "6",   7.56, 7.66, 7.56-7.66,
  "7",   9.34, 8.58, 9.34-8.58,
  "8",   7.86,6.69, 7.86-6.69,
  "9",   3.17, 3.16, 3.17-3.16,
  "10",  13.40, 11.18, 13.40-11.18,
  "NA",   6.46, 5.03, 6.46-5.03,
  "Total", 100, 100, 100.00-100.00)

dist3 %>%
  filter(DV %in% c(0:10)) %>%
  group_by(DV) %>%
  summarise(pval = t.test(x = Y1, y = Y2)$p.value)
#> Error in `summarise()`:
#> ℹ In argument: `pval = t.test(x = Y1, y = Y2)$p.value`.
#> ℹ In group 1: `DV = "0"`.
#> Caused by error in `t.test.default()`:
#> ! not enough 'x' observations
#> Backtrace:
#>      ▆
#>   1. ├─dist3 %>% filter(DV %in% c(0:10)) %>% group_by(DV) %>% ...
#>   2. ├─dplyr::summarise(., pval = t.test(x = Y1, y = Y2)$p.value)
#>   3. ├─dplyr:::summarise.grouped_df(., pval = t.test(x = Y1, y = Y2)$p.value)
#>   4. │ └─dplyr:::summarise_cols(.data, dplyr_quosures(...), by, "summarise")
#>   5. │   ├─base::withCallingHandlers(...)
#>   6. │   └─dplyr:::map(quosures, summarise_eval_one, mask = mask)
#>   7. │     └─base::lapply(.x, .f, ...)
#>   8. │       └─dplyr (local) FUN(X[[i]], ...)
#>   9. │         └─mask$eval_all_summarise(quo)
#>  10. │           └─dplyr (local) eval()
#>  11. ├─stats::t.test(x = Y1, y = Y2)
#>  12. ├─stats:::t.test.default(x = Y1, y = Y2)
#>  13. │ └─base::stop("not enough 'x' observations")
#>  14. └─base::.handleSimpleError(...)
#>  15.   └─dplyr (local) h(simpleError(msg, call))
#>  16.     └─dplyr (local) handler(cnd)
#>  17.       └─rlang::abort(message, class = error_class, parent = parent, call = error_call)
```

You can perform a t-test to compare Y1 and Y2 across all of your DV categories (i.e. is there a difference between all Y1 values and all Y2 values?), e.g.

```r
dist3 %>%
  filter(DV %in% c(0:10)) %>%
  summarise(pval = t.test(x = Y1, y = Y2)$p.value)
#> # A tibble: 1 × 1
#>    pval
#>   <dbl>
#> 1 0.947
```

<sup>Created on 2023-04-28 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Is that your intended outcome?

Comment: No. The ask is whether the amount of people who picked 0 in Y1 is statistically different from the amount of people who picked 0 in Y2. So it's not the difference between the answers, its the difference in share of people who picked each of the answers across years. I'm using percentage because the sample size is different between the two years. I also am not sure the ask itself makes sense. For example is that -3.13% drop in 0 responses statistically significant?

Comment: Yes, I understand; unfortunately I don't believe you can compare Y1 and Y2 percentages in that way using a t-test, sorry @ibm. You can use a chi-squared test to compare two values (i.e. do these values differ significantly from what was expected), but a t-test compares distributions (by definition, more than one value). I suggest you ask this question at https://stats.stackexchange.com/ for help with 'what stats should I use?'